# Inconsistent units using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong but I noticed that if I try to summarize data that include duration data using dplyr the units that are returned are inconsistent/incorrect. Why summarize get the wrong units?

```
library(lubridate)
time1 <- as.POSIXct("2018-06-27 12:08 AM")
time2 <- as.POSIXct("2018-02-15 16:33:58")

a <- data.frame(
  time = time1 + 1:3600 * 60
)

b <- data.frame(
  time = time2 + 1:3600 * 3600
)

c <- bind_rows(a, b, .id = "group")

# Units are incorrect
c %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(
    median(diff(time))
  )

# They should look more like this
aggregate(time ~ group, data = c, FUN = function(x) median(diff(x)))
aggregate(time ~ group, data = c, FUN = function(x) units(median(diff(x))))
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `difftime` and specify the `unit`

```
library(dplyr)
c %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
    summarise(
    Median = median(difftime(time, lag(time, default = first(time)), 
        unit = "min")))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  group Median 
#  <chr> <drtn> 
#1 1      1 mins
#2 2     60 mins
```